# Can't install Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2015

I'll get straight to the point here.

I've been having loads of problems installing Visual Studio 2015 Community recently. I previously had Visual Studio 2012, but decided to uninstall it and install 2015 since I've started using 2015 at college.

Originally I was using Windows 7 Professional when I was having the issues, but it persists with Windows 10. The exact issue is that when I try to install Visual Studio, it progresses a little bit and then stops at "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x86 Debug Runtime - 14.0.24210" and then doesn't progress past that. It will keep installing that for as long as I let it, and when I try to stop the download, it will not close and I will have to restart my PC. See here:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c7qF.png)

I contacted Microsoft support, which, I have to say, is appalling, and they recommended that I try to install it after performing a clean boot. I did that, and it seemed to be working, but I got multiple other errors. See here:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgVdZ.png)

As I need this programme to help with college work, you can see how this would be a huge inconvenience for me, and since Microsoft support is so terrible, I decided to come here to ask for help.

So, would you please help me figure this out?

Comment: Do  you click all the defaults when installing? The visual Studio 2015 doesn't come with a C++ compiler, only C# I believe. So you need to install C++ with it. It should be an option if you look through the windows during installation process and not do the defaults.

Comment: Look at this web: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx

Comment: I don't get that option when running the installer. Originally, I had the option to select or deselect which languages I wanted, but now when I run it it just goes straight to "initialising setup" and then starts acquiring and installing the software.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60k1461a.aspx, try looking at this.

Comment: To find the detail error message, you can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder, then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: Is this what you need?
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlBKAPi9mikPqFpt6g9ofzuQiN1z

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the log file, I found the error message 'The older version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x86 Debug Runtime - 14.0.24210 cannot be removed', you can have a try with the following to troubleshot this issue:

1. Make sure run the installer as administrator.
2. Go to Control Panel—Programs and Features and if you can find any versions of Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable, right-click and repair. After that, re-run the VS installer as administrator to repair. If not works, uninstall the installed Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable versions and re-run the VS installer again.
3. You can also use the MsiInv tool: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2005/07/01/using-msiinv-to-gather-information-about-what-is-installed-on-a-computer/ to obtain all Windows Installer products, features and components that Windows Installer thinks are installed on your computer, then manually uninstall the Visual C++ 2015 x86 Debug Runtime - 14.0.24210 by running msiexec /x  command. After that, re-run the VS installer as administrator.
4. Download the Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable from https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=48145 and install it, then re-run the VS installer to repair.

Comment: I uninstalled the C++ Redistributable, and installed it with the link you provided, then I ran the VS installer as an administrator.

I got error messages saying that the network resources "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0780A1F4-A089-3156-9996-6A1DC1342A96}v14.0.23918\packages\vcRedistD14\debug\x86\", "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5DFEB60C-501E-375A-9967-99BBCB6150C5}v14.0.23918\packages\vcRedistD14\debug\x64\" and "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8CE767E5-878E-47F9-87C2-813D72D06BAE}v1.0.25123.00\packages\vs_vshub\" are unavailable.

The fatal error is due to the Visual Studio Services Hub

Comment: Since the VS installer found those 3 specific folders are unavailable, you can confirm the existing of those folders on your computer, if they are appearing, you need to check the administrator account have enough permission on those folder, like ownership and full control. If you cannot find, you can copy it from your friends or colleagues who installed successfully the same VS version as your, or manually create those folders like {0780A1F4-A089-3156-9996-6A1DC1342A96}v14.0.23918 and find the required files from the ISO file of VS community 2015, you can download the ISO file to try it.

Comment: I done as you suggested and found that I have no files by that name. My friend who successfully installed VS 2015 agreed to help, so I sent him the names of the files I needed, however apparently he doesn't have those files either. I thought I was getting somewhere, however this complicates things, I think.

Comment: Did you install any VS 2015 previous versions? I found those missing folder under C:\ProgramData\Package Cache and the ISO file of VS enterprise 2015 with update 2 on my side, not sure it relates to the different versions or not. If you installed any previous VS 2015 no-community edition before, uninstall it completed using the command: like vs_enterprise.exe /uninstall /force in the command prompt. Or to get the missing folders, try to download the ISO file of VS 2015 with update 2 from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/hh442898.aspx. If not works, share the latest logs

Comment: I tried to find the files I need on that download link you provided, however I can't download anything as it says I need a subscription to do so.

Comment: I shared this 3 folders in here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atv5QNuFrncKdqDrm_TK_m0xhlE and you can have a try with it, if the installation still failed, you can collect and share the latest installation log like before.

Comment: I've put all the folders into the package cache, but I'm still getting the same error.
Here's the log: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlBKAPi9mikPqFwZK7MwKvvzZzU9
The error message I'm getting is that they're on a network resource which is unavailable.

Comment: I have checked the log file and found those 3 components ‘Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x86 Debug Runtime - 14.0.24210’, ‘Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Debug Runtime - 14.0.24210’ and ‘Microsoft Visual Studio Services Hub’ failed to remove which caused by Source is invalid. You can use the MsiInv tool that I mentioned before and use the uninstall them by running msiexec /x <product code>. Or use the VisualStudioUninstaller: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller to uninstall the VS.

Comment: I don't feel like I'm getting anywhere with this. I've tried so many things now, and the outcome is always the same. Would I be able to install it to a usb stick, and run it from there, or would I get the same error when installing?

Comment: Now the main blocked issue is the old versions of those 3 components cannot be removed and make the installation failed, you can try to use the PSMSI command: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/14/how-to-install-visual-studio-to-another-directory-when-a-pre-release-is-installed/ to find and remove all components related to the VS 2015, then reinstall it. As far as I know, the VS is recommended to install in the system drive and it can help you to avoid the unnecessary issue.

Comment: I've tried that, but the same issue is repeating. I reinstalled VS 2012 Express, and that install worked fine, so is it just an issue with the version?

Comment: Try this tool:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed to repair corrupted registry keys that blocked installing programs, then run the VS 2015 installer as administrator, if the same issue persists, open registry table and search with GUID like ‘{0780A1F4-A089-3156-9996-6A1DC1342A96}’ and remove those registry keys, reboot the computer and run the installer again, if the error about the component is missing, do the same to others. Before modifying the registry table, back up it firstly, in case we need to recover it.

Comment: I removed all the registry keys, restarted my PC, and ran the installer as an admin again, but I still get the same error: The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.

Comment: Refer to the error message, you need to run the above FixIt tool:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed again, if not works, when you meet this error message, you need to manually configure the path on your drive, like "raid10" in this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0ebbcc27-2763-460a-b10e-682a9e305e31/the-feature-you-are-trying-to-use-is-on-a-network-resource-that-is-unavailable?forum=vssetup